# NumberPicker is not working properly if containing 3 or less values in Android

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-number-picker

So I'm trying to make a working NumberPicker that wraps together, but when the NumberPicker contains three values or less it doesn't wrap. Also scrolling is super choppy / barely possible with three values. Is there a workaround for this?

My NumberPicker will sometimes contain less than three values and sometimes more than three values and I want it to be wrapped all the time unless it only contains one item.

Here's my code in onCreateView:

````
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_fragment, container, false);
    NumberPicker picker = view.findViewById(R.id.mPicker);

    picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(null);

    String[] values = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};
    picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setMaxValue(values.length - 1);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(values);

    picker.setValue(0);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet, container, false);
    NumberPicker picker = view.findViewById(R.id.mPicker);

    picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(null);

    String[] values = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};

    /*When using the values array below, the wrapping works as intended*/
    //String[] values = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"};

    picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setMaxValue(values.length - 1);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(values);

    picker.setValue(0);```
````